# how to split string using comma but ignore on certain condition?

Tags: java, java-8

I want to split below string

```
{"address":"XXXXXX","amount":"0.25"},{"address":"AAAAAA","amount":"0.25"}
```

into two values

```
{"address":"XXXXXX","amount":"0.25"}
{"address":"AAAAAA","amount":"0.25"}
```

Comment: why not split on "},{". You'll need to add the removed brackets later on, though

Comment: You surely should be using a JSON library for this.

Comment: if i split using }, then it gives output like {"address":"XXXXXX","amount":"0.25"

Comment: Iterate the string, counting opening and closing brackets. When there are net zero open brackets, split the string there using substring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a recommended thing to parse json the way you are doing but in case you really wanna just split, you can do so using lookarounds using regex. Here is the java code for same.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    String s = "{\"address\":\"XXXXXX\",\"amount\":\"0.25\"},{\"address\":\"AAAAAA\",\"amount\":\"0.25\"}";
    String[] data = s.split("(?<=\\}),(?=\\{)");
    Arrays.asList(data).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Prints,

```
{"address":"XXXXXX","amount":"0.25"}
{"address":"AAAAAA","amount":"0.25"}
```